# Elasticsearch template query to search query conversion

Tags: templates, elasticsearch

I try to convert a template query to a search query to use the csv converter.

My template query looks like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search/template?pretty' -d '
{
 "file": "yJmeterResult"
}'
```

Regrading to QueryDSL documentation, the search query for the template should look like this:
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-template-query.html)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search' -d '
{
 "query": {
  "template": {
   "file": "yJmeterResult"
  }
 }
}'
```

But I only get an error:

```
RemoteTransportException[[Everyman][localhost/127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [
{
 "query": {
  "template": {
   "file": "yJmeterResult"
  }
 }
}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }
```

Any hints how the search query must look like to execute the template?

Comment: Can you share the contents of "yJmeterResult" file? Perhaps there is a syntax error in the template itself.

Comment: My jMeterResult.mustache looks like this. But the query against /search/template works fine.

Comment: `{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
  "byLabels": {
   "terms": {"field": "label.raw"},
   "aggs": {
    "byRange": {
     "range": {
      "field": "elapsedTime",
      "ranges": [
       {"from": 0,"to": 1000},
       {"from": 1000,"to": 2000},
       {"from": 2000,"to": 3000}
      ],"keyed": true
}}}}},
 "query": {
  "filtered": {
   "query": {
    "query_string": {"query": "*","analyze_wildcard": true}
   },
   "filter": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [
      {
       "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
         "gte": 1453996863602,"lte": 1455000632292,"format": "epoch_millis"
        }
}}]}}}}}`